# Create a Chrome options layout like

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

How can I recreate this layout for my site? (frame-over-frame)
Does it use a standard JavaScript library? 
I'm looking for JavaScript/CSS (or tutorial)...

[image: Chrome options layout]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not frames.

The most relevant techniques for Chrome's settings / Webstore page are:

- CSS: [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow) - To show a shadow.
- CSS: [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index) - To show the layers in the correct order
- JavaScript: [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) - To change the URL.

The full CSS and HTML code can be viewed by using `Inspect element` at `chrome://settings`.